# 5650m/4250m AMD/ATI disable discrete gpu?

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics, switchable-graphics

I want to disable 5650m, as dpm keeps making it dynpwr for a while and when it switches to dynoff the laptop will freeze for a while.

I have tried acpi_call_GUI. It finds `\SB.PCI0.AGP.VGA.PX02` and freezes to a black screen with frozen mouse.

Can someone point me to a possible solution?

Seems like the dpm is just broken for this laptop as the 5650m just produces problems. I would just like to make 5650m show OFF completely.

18.04 here.